# Eclipse not rebuilding

Tags: eclipse

I'm having what I think are eclipse issues.  This has happened multiple times when I make structural changes to my code organization, moving stuff into different packages and such.  Something is not rebuilding, cleaning or is out of synch.

So, I have one project that is showing an error at the top level and one with an !.  Last time this happened I think I removed something and put it right back.   The manifestation of the error is that Tomcat can't load one of my beans which means the constructor fails.

I've cleaned and rebuilt the projects to no avail.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: go to Windows->Show View -> Problems, then clik on the project marked with error signal and Eclipse will shows you what it is wrong

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the help.  Turns out there was a missing empty source folder in the build path.   The problems view is a visible in the Java perspective.